# Найти фразеологизм

Tags: фразеология

Найдите фразеологизм (существительное с предлогом).

*Всё надобно стараться

С погребной стороны за дело приниматься;

А если иначе, все будет без пути.*

*Хозяин некакий стал лестницу мести;

Да начал, не умея взяться,

С ступеней нижних месть. Хоть с нижней сор сметет,

А с верхней сор опять на нижнюю спадет.

«Не бестолков ли ты? — ему тут говорили,

Которые при этом были. —

Кто снизу лестницу метет?»*

*На что бы походило,

Когда б в правлении, в каком бы то ни было,

Не с вышних степеней, а с нижних начинать

Порядок наблюдать?*
[**И. И. Хемницер. Лестница**](https://vsebasni.ru/hemnicer/lestnica.html)

Comment: _С **погребной** стороны..._ === По-моему, надо _"с поТребной"_.

Comment: Попробуйте сами, Лира.  А мы подтвердим, если правильно.

Comment: я думаю, что это"без пути"?

Comment: Я думаю, что Вы правильно думаете.

Comment: Путь-5 знач. слова- Польза, толк (просторечное). В этом парне пути не будет. В мальчишке будет п.http://ozhegov.textologia.ru/definit/put/?q=742&n=199540

Comment: slava1947 , у Хемницера именно так: "с погребной" , это 18 век, нам теперь не разобраться, при чём там погреб

Comment: _у Хемницера именно так: "с погребной"_ === Ну, может и так. "С потребной" мне попалось вот здесь: http://www.wisdomcode.info/ru/poetry/authors/54975.html

Comment: А я открыла печатный вариант, сначала удивилась этому Г,             ( выпуск уже новый, без корректоров). Потом пробежалась по интернетным текстам, везде Г , пришла к выводу: так должно быть, это я не понимаю чего-то. А Вы молодец, нашли верный, это, конечно, правильно - потребный.

Answer (score 1):

[**Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка**](http://phraseology.academic.ru/10254/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7):
**Без пути**
*Прост.* Попусту, зря, напрасно.

[**Большой толково-фразеологический словарь Михельсона**](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/michelson_new/456/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7):
**без пути**
(иноск.) — попусту, напрасно, без толку, без цели.

*Встречались, конечно, и другие, которые в этом смысле не клали охулки на руку, но... они делали это умненько, с толком, а не **без пути**, как Савельцев.*

В современном языке выражение употребляется редко (басня написана в 1782 году).
А вот образованное от него прилагательное ***беспутный*** используется часто и  повсеместно (*иноск.* в ком (в чем) нет пути, толку, порядка; *разг.* легкомысленный, неосновательный, беспорядочный // ветреный, развратный).